# How to force user to enable Java script?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My WordPress site's revenue depends on Java script. So when the visitor disable Java script for my site, how can I force him to enable Java script?

Comment: Programmatically you can't, it would be kinda pointless(for the end user) for there to be a user setting that someone else can turn back on.

Comment: ^and rightfully so. If the user has disabled JavaScript, I would sure hope you can't "force" them to re-enable it.

Comment: You shouldn't force the user to enable anything, the same way you can't force someone to visit your site. If they are there, it's because they want to see your content. So, a simple message like "This site requires Javascript" is enough.

Comment: Just have a blank page with a single JS line that calls the entire rest of the website and loads it in. If they don't have JS enabled, they don't see the website.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't. The web environment is intentionally made open, so the viewer can adapt websites as they like.

You can however make it harder by having javascript do things to the page that makes it readable, so you have to have javascript enbled to see it. Most trivial would be to hide the elements through CSS display:none and turn them on from javascript. The user can disable javascript as soon as the page has rendered though.

You can show content specifically for non-javascript users using the <noscript> tag.

Comment: friends I'm beginner and little bit greedy. Always think about increasing revenue

Comment: Stated another way, a browser should never let any web site or application take control of a user's browser.